# MInecraft server java.sql.SQLException: Unknown error 1045

Tags: mysql, server, minecraft

I am running a 1.19.2 minecraft server on PurPur, and I am using luckperms. One day I am got a report from a player, because he got an error message, and can't join. I watched the console quickly, and I see this error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unknown error 1045
        at me.lucko.luckperms.lib.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[?:?]
        at me.lucko.luckperms.lib.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[?:?]
        at me.lucko.luckperms.lib.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:833) ~[?:?]
        at me.lucko.luckperms.lib.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:453) ~[?:?]
        at me.lucko.luckperms.lib.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246) ~[?:?]
        at me.lucko.luckperms.lib.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) ~[?:?]
        at me.lucko.luckperms.lib.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[?:?]
        at me.lucko.luckperms.lib.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[?:?]
        at me.lucko.luckperms.lib.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[?:?]
        at me.lucko.luckperms.lib.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[?:?]
        at me.lucko.luckperms.lib.hikari.pool.HikariPool.access$100(HikariPool.java:71) ~[?:?]
        at me.lucko.luckperms.lib.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:726) ~[?:?]
        at me.lucko.luckperms.lib.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:712) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623) ~[?:?]
```

What can I do with this error?

Comment: Welcome on STackOverflow. As you're not developer of LuckPerms plugin, this website is not made for you. For your issue, it's better to ask to their support, of check the [wiki](https://luckperms.net/wiki/Storage-types). Actually, it seems you wrongly config the database (wrong login/password etc)